# QDialog disappears after creation, but stays modal

Tags: qt, dialog, modal-dialog

Sometimes, a modal popup dialog (`QDialog` subclass) will disappear or hide 'on its own'; it will continue to block all events to the main page but will be invisible, thus forcing a program restart.  This will happen on some runs of the program but not others, with what appear to be identical inputs.  Using the debugger, I can see that the program is indeed stopped on the `exec()` function call.  However since the dialog is invisible there is no way to interact with it.  The dialog is created with

```
QDialog( parent, Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint )
```

and

```
setModal(true);
```

How can I figure out what's going on here?

**Edit 1:** A little more code although I don't think it adds much:

```
    ModalDialog dialog( this, "Display text" );
    dialog.Run(); //Just calls exec()
```

It's really as simple as this.  However, the call stack might be more revealing; `Hooli.exe!ModalDialog::Run(bool async)` occurs *twice*--how could that happen?

> ntdll.dll!773901fd()    Unknown     [Frames below may be incorrect and/or
>   missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]
>     ntdll.dll!773901fd()    Unknown     KernelBase.dll!758e170b()   Unknown 
>     KernelBase.dll!758e1641()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec77d3()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ed087a()   Unknown     Qt5Cored.dll!6659d658() Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64249590()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6429fe0f()  Unknown     Qt5Cored.dll!662b5eed() Unknown 
>     msvcr110d.dll!_unlock(int locknum) Line 366 C 
>     msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line
>   1270  C++     msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse)
>   Line 1267 C++     Qt5Cored.dll!66272413() Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64384d57()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64249590()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6429fe0f()  Unknown     msvcr110d.dll!_unlock(int
>   locknum) Line 366 C   msvcr110d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData)
>   Line 57   C++     msvcr110d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData) Line
>   56    C++     Qt5Cored.dll!6668b5b5() Unknown 
>     Qt5Cored.dll!662b5eed() Unknown     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64384d57()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64253b6d()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64251cd5()  Unknown     verifier.dll!10acab48() Unknown 
>     verifier.dll!10ac9807() Unknown     verifier.dll!10ac9813() Unknown 
>     Qt5Cored.dll!662b5eed() Unknown     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64253b6d()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64251cd5()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64249590()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6429fe0f()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64249590()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6429fe0f()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64262543()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6429f909()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6423f6e4()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6470af14()  Unknown     Qt5Cored.dll!6651591b() Unknown 
>     verifier.dll!10ac98bc() Unknown     KernelBase.dll!758e5500()   Unknown 
>     KernelBase.dll!758e55f3()   Unknown     imm32.dll!755f1db3()    Unknown 
>     imm32.dll!755f1ed8()    Unknown     msctf.dll!75346306()    Unknown 
>     msctf.dll!753462ec()    Unknown     msctf.dll!7534467c()    Unknown 
>     msctf.dll!753441b5()    Unknown     msctf.dll!753441b5()    Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec62fa()   Unknown     msctf.dll!753441b5()    Unknown 
>     msctf.dll!753441b5()    Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6ce9()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64284b8f()  Unknown     msctf.dll!753441b5()    Unknown 
>     msctf.dll!753441b5()    Unknown     user32.dll!74ecd69b()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ecd762()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ecd71e()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec62fa()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6ce9()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec966e()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ecd70c()   Unknown 
>     verifier.dll!10ac98bc() Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6210()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6b34()   Unknown     qwindowsd.dll!1971dad1()    Unknown 
>     msctf.dll!753441b5()    Unknown     user32.dll!74ec62fa()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6ce9()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6ce9()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec966e()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec96d5()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ecda5b()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec978a()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ecda73()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ecd9bc()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ecadb3()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec62fa()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6ce9()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec966e()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ecd70c()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6210()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6b34()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6b00()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6b00()   Unknown     qwindowsd.dll!1971dad1()    Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec6ce9()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec6d91()   Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec966e()   Unknown     user32.dll!74ec96d5()   Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!642a88a6()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6429f820()  Unknown     Qt5Cored.dll!662b5eed() Unknown 
>     Qt5Cored.dll!662b5eed() Unknown     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64384d57()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64253b6d()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64251cd5()  Unknown 
>     msvcr110d.dll!_heap_alloc_base(unsigned int size) Line 57   C 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64235309()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64236cb7()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!644f2e63()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!644f0c32()  Unknown     Hooli.exe!ModalDialog::Run(bool
>   async) Line 195   C++     Qt5Cored.dll!6654df39() Unknown 
>     Qt5Cored.dll!6654d981() Unknown     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6470d6da()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!643a6df8()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!643a6417()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!643a5852()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6429f33d()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!643a53b1()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6446703b()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!64253b5e()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!642505fb()  Unknown     Qt5Cored.dll!6650c2e4() Unknown 
>     user32.dll!74ec8940()   Unknown     uxtheme.dll!70196e9f()  Unknown 
>     qwindowsd.dll!197447cc()    Unknown     Qt5Cored.dll!6650804c() Unknown 
>     Qt5Cored.dll!66508252() Unknown     Qt5Widgetsd.dll!644f0c45()  Unknown 
>     Qt5Cored.dll!662bcfbd() Unknown
>   Hooli.exe!ModalDialog::Run(bool async) Line 195   C++     Hooli.exe!Hooli::HomePage::PerformFileOperation(Hooli::HomePage::eFileOperation
>   operation) Line 727   C++     Hooli.exe!Hooli::HomePage::onCopy() Line
>   960   C++     Hooli.exe!Hooli::HomePage::qt_static_metacall(QObject * _o,
>   QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void * * _a) Line 242  C++

**Edit 2**: Here's the constructor for ModalDialog:

```
ModalDialog::ModalDialog( QWidget* pParent, const QString& rTitle, const QString& rDescription, eButtonWords words, eModalType type )
    : QDialog( pParent, Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint ),
    ...
{
    //We must have a parent to inherit the stylesheet
    Q_ASSERT( pParent );

    setModal( true );

    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

    mpDialogBackground = new QWidget( this );
    mpDialogBackground->setObjectName( "ModalBackground" );

    mpTitle = new QLabel( rTitle, this );
    mpTitle->setObjectName( "ModalTitle" );
    mpTitle->setWordWrap( true );
    mpTitle->setStyleSheet( QString("font: bold %1pt; ").arg(FONT_SIZE) );

    switch( type )
    {
    case ModalType_ACTION_REQUIRED:
        {
            mpTitle->setProperty( "ModalType", "ActionRequired" );
        }
        break;
    case ModalType_CONFIRM:
        {
            mpTitle->setProperty( "ModalType", "Confirm" );
        }
        break;
    case ModalType_SUCCESS:
        {
            mpTitle->setProperty( "ModalType", "Success" );
        }
        break;
    case ModalType_WARNING:
        {
            mpTitle->setProperty( "ModalType", "Warning" );
        }
        break;
    case ModalType_FAILURE:
        {
            mpTitle->setProperty( "ModalType", "Failure" );
        }
        break;
    case ModalType_DEFAULT:
    default:
        //do nothing
        break;
    }

    mpIconLabel = new QLabel( this );

    mpDescription = new QLabel( rDescription, this );
    mpDescription->setObjectName( "ModalDescription" );
    mpDescription->setWordWrap( true );
    mpDescription->setStyleSheet( QString("font: %1pt;").arg(FONT_SIZE) );

    mpButtonArea = new QWidget( this );
    mpButtonArea->setObjectName( "ModalButtonArea" );

    mpOkButton = new QPushButton( this );
    mpOkButton->resize( DEFAULT_BUTTON_WIDTH, DEFAULT_BUTTON_HEIGHT ); 
    connect( mpOkButton, SIGNAL( released() ), this, SLOT( OnYesOk() ) );

    mpCancelButton = new QPushButton( this );
    mpCancelButton->resize( DEFAULT_BUTTON_WIDTH, DEFAULT_BUTTON_HEIGHT ); 
    connect( mpCancelButton, SIGNAL( released() ), this, SLOT( OnNoCancel() ) );

    mpSpecialCancelButton = new QPushButton( this );
    mpSpecialCancelButton->resize( DEFAULT_BUTTON_WIDTH, DEFAULT_BUTTON_HEIGHT ); 
    connect( mpSpecialCancelButton, SIGNAL( released() ), this, SLOT( OnSpecialCancel() ) );
    mpSpecialCancelButton->hide();

    setPixmapBackground( GuiCommon::cPixmap( ":/mypixmap.png" ), true );

    SetButtonStrings( mOkText, mCancelText, mYesText, mNoText );

    //The actual widget size is the size of the window because
    //a semi-transparent cover is put over the background.
    setFixedSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
    SetSize( DEFAULT_POPUP_WIDTH, DEFAULT_POPUP_HEIGHT );
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some real code, maybe broken down to the important pieces? What you describe is definitely no standard behaviour. (It sounds a bit like if it happens sometimes that the QDialog instance is destroyed before exec can finish sometimes but this is just a guess)

Comment: @IceFire See my edit.  The code isn't revealing but the stack trace has clues.

Comment: Okay, if Run just calls exec then it is probably not in there twice... Your constructor could also be interesting

Comment: @IceFire I don't understand your comment--`Run()` *is* in there twice, just ctrl-F it.  I've added the ctor code now, it adds widgets, buttons, sizes things, etc. but no smoking gun I can see.

Comment: What is your setup (Qt version, OS, ...) ?

Comment: @Ilya Qt 5.5, Windows 7, IDE is VS, compiling with msvc2012

Comment: Yes, I know that it is in there twice, my comment was supposed to say that I am not entirely sure that Run() really calls exec without doing anything else. Apart from that, it could also be the case that some other statement is run concurrently, e.g. that the method where the dialog is created is called twice... I think we would need to see more code

Comment: @IceFire Line 195 of `Run()` is `exec();`.  The test `(async == false)` is the only thing that occurs prior, which evaluates to true (or else line 195 wouldn't be entered).  After that is the line `return result;` (an enum value) and the function exits.

Comment: Okay, maybe the constructor sets some flags or something that disturbs error-free execution? Or does the error also occur if you use a normal QDialog instead of your ModalDialog? Somewhere the error has to be

Comment: @IceFire All the flags relevant to modality, visibility have been shown.  But I do expect that it has something to do with it being a custom widget.  Also, this only happens after several successive uses of the dialog.

Comment: hm, strange... you might try logging the visibility property and all the events that run through the dialog prior to disappearing... Without more code it is really hard to say a lot. I have no idea about custom widgets, though... if they are compiled separately, checking for calling conventions, dynamic dll/dynamic (not dll) might help, sometimes strange errors occur. Also, you might check for memory leaks, which is a good idea for any application anyway. I use VisualLeakDetector... maybe, someone else has a better idea

Comment: @IceFire I think your suggestion to check memory leaks is on point, I'm logging events now and even in the error state calling `raise()` has no effect despite `isVisible()` returning true.  I am going to attack memory issues and see if the problem magically disappears on its own.